# Why shows no input file specified in Codeigniter on Online Linux Server?

Tags: codeigniter

My codeigniter project under one folder shows **No input file specified**. in linux server.

Worked perfectly in local server... Problem occured only in online server

my project url is http://kenknack.com/healthcare/

Given all connections correctly with database connections.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think people can help you without seeing server-side code.

Comment: which code?.. Which page?...

Comment: Make sure the controller files have first letter only upper case on filename and classname

Comment: changed also not worked @wolfgang1983

Comment: Have you tried with index.php `http://kenknack.com/index.php/healthcare/` if that works then you may need a htacess file

Comment: yes working with index.php @wolfgang Thanks..

Comment: Added htaccess under the healthcare folder. But not worked

Comment: make sure its outside of the application folder and on the config.php also `$config['index_page'] = '';` here are some htaccess https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter